# How to load two fields from ListItemCollection into Datatable

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint, datatable

Below I am accessing a SharePoint list and feeding it into a ListItemCollection which is working, but what I would like to do is feed two fields from the list into a DataTable (so the dt would have two columns), but I couldn't find anything that meets my requirements online. I'm also new to this. What would be the best way to do this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string siteUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"];
    string clientID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
    string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];
    using (ClientContext cc = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientID, clientSecret))
    {
        Web site = cc.Web;
        List targetList = site.Lists.GetByTitle("Companies");

        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='CompanyID'/><Value Type='Text'>Cumbria</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>";
        ListItemCollection collListItem = targetList.GetItems(query);

        cc.Load(collListItem);
        cc.ExecuteQuery();

        if (collListItem.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No items found.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Items found:\n");
            foreach (ListItem targetListItem in collListItem)
                Console.WriteLine(targetListItem["Reference"]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help on this please?

Comment: Hi @CGarden, could you please explain if you are getting some kind of an exception or something? What type are these fields that you mention? Do you have a problem with the definition of the Datatable or the list item fetching from sharepoint ?

Comment: have you seen this before trying to get results from sharepoint ? -> https://umeaworks.com/2020/03/10/load-fields-dynamically-when-using-sharepoint-csom/

Comment: No exceptions are thrown, the above code works. But I am creating a listitemcollection, i'd like to create a data table instead. And I don't know how to do this.

Comment: So as a result you need an object of the DataTable class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-7.0)??

Comment: I'll give that a go thank you. Just wasn't sure the code to blend the list into a DataTable. But I'll check your code example thanks.